# Django abstract user model not migrating

Tags: python, django, authentication

So I am working on implementing a custom user model, and to do so i followed tutorial '[this](https://www.fomfus.com/articles/how-to-use-email-as-username-for-django-authentication-removing-the-username) tutorial.

These are the models:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractUser):
    """User model."""

    username = None
    email = EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()
```

I am now trying to run `python3 manage.py migrate` and I get this error:

```
[wtreston] ~/gdrive/mysite2/ $ python3 manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, reviews, sessions, users
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 164, in handle
    pre_migrate_apps = pre_migrate_state.apps
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 218, in apps
    return StateApps(self.real_apps, self.models)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 295, in __init__
    raise ValueError("\n".join(error.msg for error in errors))
ValueError: The field admin.LogEntry.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'users.user', but app 'users' doesn't provide model 'user'.
The field reviews.Answer.student was declared with a lazy reference to 'users.user', but app 'users' doesn't provide model 'user'.
The field reviews.ReviewBlock.teacher was declared with a lazy reference to 'users.user', but app 'users' doesn't provide model 'user'.
The field users.Student.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'users.user', but app 'users' doesn't provide model 'user'.
The field users.Teacher.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'users.user', but app 'users' doesn't provide model 'user'.
```

In my settings.py I have this line `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'`
. and when I reference the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` with ForeignKeys, I first have `from mysite import settings` and then have `ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)`

Any help would be helpful! Thanks

Comment: `users.User` has `abstract = True`?

Comment: @schwobaseggl added the two models I am using as I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: what does your migration file look like?

Comment: You should generally import settings from `django.conf` which will provide all the settings in your `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` and all the necessary default values. Also, try using django's `get_user_model()` function instead of `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`

Comment: @schwobaseggl Ok. I have made all the changes you suggested, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: It seems you didn\`t add correct User model reference in settings. Have you correctly specified `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in `settings.py`? It should be `AUTH_USER_MODEL = '<AppName>.User>'`

Comment: @Michael this is the line I have in my settings.py `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
`

Comment: @wtreston does your `models.py` file with your User model lies really inside  `users` App? It is called so?

Comment: @Michael yup it does

Comment: @wtreston didn\`t you forget to register app in `settings.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have inherited `AbstractUser` for your custom user model and you are inheriting `BaseUserManager` for `UserManager`
modify your manager like below by inheriting `UserManager`:

```
class MyUserManager(UserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **kwargs):
        # override this method

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **kwargs):
        # override this method
```

clean up migrations and database first and then apply migration with this changes.

Comment: what do you mean by `clean up migrations and database first and then apply migration with this changes.` I can delete the most recent migration, however I dont know what you mean by clean up the database

Comment: cleaning migrations won't delete any existing created table in database. for simply you can drop all tables of database.. like fresh start